# Spring Boot 1.5.9 character encoding issue

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm getting character encoding error explanation below:

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3 and when I run my project from IDE with main class my rest service works fine, log4j prints :

> "Türkiye"

but when I get .jar file and execute from powershell log4j prints:

> "T³rkiye"

and rest service fails. I tried on my localhost both of cases. I think maven not executing jvmArguments.

Maven:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.kafein.merge.application.Application</mainClass>
                <executable>true</executable>
                <jvmArguments>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</jvmArguments>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Check out this  [article](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/), you'll found there the way to fixing this problems

Answer (score 0):

You can run your maven app including the following option `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8`. As in:

```
$ java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar <artifactname>.jar
```

If you would like a permanent fix, export the maven options as:

```
$ export JAVA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

But this truely depends on how you intend to deploy your app.

**Note:** Let me know how you intend to deploy your app!